# "Why? - "No reason" auf Deutsch

Tags: english-to-german, proverb, english

Wenn man jemanden etwas fragt, und danach zurück gefragt wird mit

> "Warum *(hast du das gefragt)*?"

wie soll man dann mit der Bedeutung des englischen "No reason" antworten?

Die direkte Übersetzung von "no reason" wäre wahrscheinlich "ohne Grund", aber ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob es hier richtig passt.

Comment: Siehe auch: [How do you say “just because” in German?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9402/1859)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was ich in solchen Fällen schon oft als Antwort gehört habe ist

> Nur so.

oder

> Nur neugierig.

oder

> Einfach so.

Answer (score 7):

Eine typische Antwort auf die Frage "Warum?" in dem genannten Sinne ist

> Einfach so.

Damit wird analog zum englischen "no reason" ausgedrückt, dass die ursprüngliche Frage keinen tieferen Sinn hatte, sondern eben "einfach so" gestellt wurde.

Answer (score 3):

Da es ein Fragen ohne Grund nicht gibt, stehen Antworten wie »Nur so« und »Einfach so« immer für die Aussage, dass man den Grund nicht nennen will [Neugier]. Hierfür sind auch andere Ausdrücke unterwegs, z. B.

> - Fiel mir gerade ein. / Ist mir gerade eingefallen.
> - Ging mir gerade [so] durch den Kopf. / Ist mir gerade [so] durch den Kopf gegangen.
> - Kam mir gerade in den Sinn. / Ist mir gerade in den Sinn gekommen.
> - Warum nicht?